# C++ class to create and evaluate Chebyshev approximations of arbitrary functions

Tags: c++, mathematics, numerical-methods, c++20

I recently needed to create a function to approximate a complex trigonometric function on an embedded system without a floating point unit and without a fast trigonometric library.  So I pulled out my ancient copy of "Numerical Recipes in C, Second Edition" by Press, Teukolsky, Vetterling and Flannery, and updated the [Chebyshev polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) approximation functions to use modern C++.

For an approximation of order \$N\$ within the range \$[-1,1]\$, the code calculates the Chebyshev approximation coefficients of the passed function \$f\$ as:
$$ c_j = \frac{2}{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N} f\left[ \cos\left(\frac{\pi(k - \frac{1}{2})}{N}\right)\right] \cos\left(\frac{\pi j (k - \frac{1}{2})}{N}\right) $$

To make the code more general, we map any arbitrary input range \$[a, b]\$ to \$[-1, 1]\$ using
$$ x' = \frac{x - \frac{1}{2}(b + a)}{\frac{1}{2}(b - a)} $$

This code then uses [Clenshaw's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clenshaw_algorithm) to evaluate the approximation.

The `demo` function takes a function to be approximated, low and high limits and the order of the approximation as inputs and calculates the coefficients and prints 100 values and the error value of the approximation at each of those points, and the maximum of the absolute error.  It then exercises the checked evaluation of the approximation (which does range checking) to provoke a thrown `std::range_error`.  The checked evaluation uses an unchecked evaluation to actually perform the Clenshaw algorithm and evaluate the approximation.

A plot of the error values for a 7th order approximation of the cosine function in the range \$[0, \frac{\pi}{2}]\$ is shown below.  It has the characteristic undulating error value of a Chebyshev approximation.
[image: error plot of 7th order Chebyshev approximation of cosine function]

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <limits>
#include <numbers>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class ChebApprox {
public:
    // given a function implementation, create a Chebyshev polynomial approximation
    ChebApprox(T lowerbound, T upperbound, unsigned n, T (*func)(T));
    // range-check evaluation of Chebyshev approximation
    T operator()(T x) const;
    // unchecked evaluation of Chebyshev approximation
    T chebeval(T x) const;
    // returns beginning iterator of coefficients list
    auto begin() const { return coefficients.cbegin(); }
    // returns ending iterator of coefficients list
    auto end() const { return coefficients.cend(); }
private:
    T lowerbound; 
    T upperbound; 
    std::vector<T> coefficients;
};

template <typename T>
ChebApprox<T>::ChebApprox(T lowerbound, T upperbound, unsigned n, T (*func)(T)) 
    : lowerbound{lowerbound}
    , upperbound{upperbound}
{
    const auto bma{(upperbound - lowerbound)/2};
    const auto bpa{(upperbound + lowerbound)/2};
    std::vector<T> f;
    f.reserve(n);
    coefficients.reserve(n);
    for (unsigned k = 0; k < n; ++k) {
        T y{std::cos(std::numbers::pi * (k + 0.5) / n)};
        f.push_back((*func)(y * bma + bpa));
    }
    const T fac = 2.0/n;
    for (unsigned j=0; j < n; ++j) {
        T sum{0};
        for (unsigned k=0; k < n; ++k) {
            sum += f[k] * std::cos(std::numbers::pi * j * (k+0.5) / n);
        }
        coefficients.push_back(fac*sum);
    }
}

template <typename T>
T ChebApprox<T>::operator()(T x) const {
    if (x < lowerbound || x > upperbound) {
        throw std::range_error("Approximation function input out of allowed range");
    }
    return chebeval(x);
}

template <typename T>
T ChebApprox<T>::chebeval(T x) const {
    T y{(2 * x - lowerbound - upperbound) / (upperbound - lowerbound)};
    T y2{2 * y};
    T d{0};
    T dd{0};
    for (auto j{coefficients.size()-1}; j; --j) {
        auto sv{d};
        d = y2 * d - dd + coefficients[j];
        dd = sv;
    }
    return y * d - dd + coefficients[0] / 2;
}

void demo(double (*func)(double), double lo, double hi, unsigned n) 
{
    ChebApprox<double> ch{lo, hi, n, func};
    std::cout << "Coefficients:\n" << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10 + 1);
    std::copy(ch.begin(), ch.end(), std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, ", "));
    std::cout << "\nEvaluation\n";
    auto delta{(hi-lo)/100};
    double maxerror{0};
    for (auto x{lo}; x < hi; x += delta) {
        auto calc{ch(x)};
        auto error{calc - func(x)};
        if (std::fabs(error) > std::fabs(maxerror)) { maxerror = error; }
        std::cout << x << '\t' << calc << '\t' << error << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << "Maximum absolute error was " << maxerror << '\n';
    try {
        auto bad{ch(hi + 1)};  // outside defined range
    } catch (std::range_error &err) {
        std::cout << err.what() << '\n';
    }
}

int main() {
    demo(std::cos, 0, std::numbers::pi/2, 7);
    demo(std::sqrt, 0, 100, 5);
}
```

Comment: What were the memory restrictions like?

Comment: Memory restrictions were fairly tight.  The target processor was a Renesas μPD78P078Y with 60K total PROM and 1K RAM. Computations on the target were actually performed using 48-bit fixed-point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Naming things

You have a bounds checking evaluation function, `operator()`, and one that doesn't do bounds checking named `chebeval()`. If the idea is to have this mimic an STL containers `operator[]` vs. `at()`, then perhaps make it more like that: have `operator()` do the unchecked evaluation, and have a member function named `at()` that does the bounds checks. Alternatively, keep the safe `operator()` as it is, but perhaps rename `chebeval()` to something else that makes it clear that this is not doing bounds checks (`eval_unchecked()`?).

You use a lot of one-letter variables, making the code hard to read. Consider making them more descriptive. Alternatively, add a comment with a link to a page/paper with the formulas and algorithms you are using, and stay as close to the notation as used in that page/paper as possible.

## Consider replacing `begin()`/`end()` with `coefficients()`

What is the begin and end of a Chebyshev approximation? Not everyone would assume that `begin()` and `end()` would give you access to the coefficients. So I would make it more explicit, and just have a member function returning a `const` reference:

```
    auto &coefficients() const { return m_coefficients; }
private:
    std::vector<T> m_coefficients;
```

And then you can use the ranges library to write for example:

```
std::ranges::copy(ch.coefficients(), std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, ", "));
```

## Consider replacing `std::vector` with a `std::array`

You know the number of coefficients up front at construction time, and it will never change. And since `class ChebApprox` is already a `template`, you can just add a template parameter for the number of coefficients instead, and then use `std::array<T, n> coefficients` for a small performance improvement.

## Allow function objects

You are using a raw function pointer for `func`, but this precludes you from passing function objects and lambdas to the constructor. In particular, you cannot create a new `ChebApprox` using a previously created `ChebApprox` as the input function. One way to do this is to use [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), like so:

```
template <typename T>
class ChebApprox {
public:
    ChebApprox(T lowerbound, T upperbound, unsigned n, std::function<T(T)> func);
```

However, as pointed out by Ray Hamel, `std::function` [might allocate memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307090/do-stdfunction-and-stdbind-do-dynamic-memory-allocation), although a decent implementation will not do so if it only needs to store a raw function pointer. But we can avoid this issue by not using `std::function`, but instead adding a template parameter for the function type:

```
template <typename T, typename Func>
class ChebApprox {
    using 
public:
    ChebApprox(T lowerbound, T upperbound, unsigned n, Func &&func);
```

The drawback of the latter method is that `Func` is now no longer constrained, and passing it an overloaded function such as `std::sqrt` will be problematic, and would require you to explicitly cast it to something unambiguous first.

## Consider using `std::midpoint()`

When calculating `bma` and `bpa`, use [`std::midpoint()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/midpoint). While unlikely to give problems, it is nonetheless safer to use than what you wrote, especially if the bounds are close to being denormal or infinity.

It might also be possible to use [`std::lerp()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/lerp) instead:

```
for (unsigned k = 0; k < n; ++k) {
    T y{1 + 0.5 * std::cos(std::numbers::pi * (k + 0.5) / n)};
    f.push_back(func(std::lerp(lowerbound, upperbound, y));
}
```

## Avoid an expensive division in `chebeval()`

Divisions are one of the most expensive CPU instructions. If you have a small number of coefficients, the calculation of `y` might take a significant fraction of the CPU time in `chebeval()`. Instead of storing `lowerbound` and `upperbound` as member variables, consider storing `lowerbound + upperbound` and `1 / (upperbound - lowerbound)` instead, so the calculation of `y` gets sped up.

The range check can be done by first calculating `y`, then checking if it is in the range \$-1\dots 1\$.

Comment: Regarding `chebeval` - it's not intended to be used outside the range; it just doesn't check for that.  It is to `operator()` as `std::vector::operator[]()` is to `std::vector::at()`.

Comment: Ah, shouldn't it be made `private` then?

Comment: I considered that, but followed the same rationale that leads to `std::vector::operator[]()` being unchecked but also `public`.

Comment: Using single-letter variables is absolutely standard in mathematics. It makes no sense to change them to something that purports to be "more meaningful" in computer code. For a standard well known algorithm like this, there is no point including a reference, but a comment identifying it as "Clenshaw's algorithm" would be useful.

Comment: @alephzero It is indeed absolutely standard in mathematics, but if you've ever read a paper, you know that they contain an explanation for every variable name used in a formula. It is missing in this code. And while you and I might know how to find a description of Clenshaw's algorithm, not everyone does, and adding a proper reference doesn't cost you anything but might greatly help someone else.

Comment: I disagree with your suggestion to use `std::function` in place of function pointers. In particular, it seems incongruous with your suggestion to replace `std::vector` with a `std::array` (`std::function` performs a dynamic allocation). Instead I would make a second template parameter `F` and replace the parameter `T (*func)(T)` with `F &&func` and the line `f.push_back(func(y*bma + bpa))` with `f.push_back(std::invoke(func, y*bma + bpa))`. This allows any appropriate invocable object to be passed to the function without any overhead.

Comment: And, speaking of, I also disagree with replacing `std::vector` with a `std::array`. What about the cases where `n` is not known at compile-time, or is large enough that the `coefficients` array would overflow the stack? If avoiding an unnecessary dynamic allocation is important, then in C++20 perhaps `coefficients` could be a `std::span<T>` with the function that constructs `ChebApprox` passing it as a parameter and owning the associated memory.

Comment: @RayHamel I wouldn't worry about `std::function` here because it is only used once in the constructor, whereas the coefficients are accessed each time you want to evaluate the approximation at a given point. But making the whole function type a template parameter is a good approach too, except maybe for a bit more boilerplate in getting the value type out of it. It is also reasonable to assume that the number of coefficients is not very large, since the whole point of this is to have a way to cheaply approximate the original function.

Comment: OP says this was to run on an embedded device with 60KB of memory, so I'm not sure we can afford to be blasé about the dynamic allocation `std::function` performs. And it might be reasonable to assume the number of coefficients is small, but if we're assuming something, especially something having to do with low-level memory allocation, we ought to make that assumption explicit with, e.g., an assertion.

Comment: @RayHamel I'm confused, you don't like the potential dynamic allocation of `std::function`, but you do recommend using `std::vector` for the coefficients, which is almost certainly going to allocate memory dynamically? Note that a decent implementation of `std::function` will not allocate memory if it is not necessary, for example if it only needs to store a raw function pointer, like in OP's example, and even if it allocates, it is only a temporary allocation. And with `std::array`, the caller can choose to make it dynamic by just using `new` to create a `ChebApprox`.